# How do viroids and virusoids cause infection to a specific host ? How could they indentify the host without protein?

Tags: virology

We know, the capsule provides specific  pathogenecity for the virus right ? Then ,  how do viroids and virusoids cause infection to a specific host ? How could they indentify the host without protein ? Seems like they could infect any possible living being ? Please make it clear

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Thank you for taking the [tour], but please also go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, I suggest adding more information about viroids and virusoids (including references and links). It would be especially helpful if you were to discuss what you have learned about their host specificity. This will both help you get better answers and demonstrate that you have done the expect prior research. Also note that your first sentence is not relevant to enveloped viruses! Thanks! 

Comment: Wikipedia says that [virusoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virusoid) have a protein coating, which presumably is involved in infectivity.